# how to download excel file onclick and how to restrict the file to be download on refresh

Tags: php, excel

My file is getting downloaded when refreshing the page but I don't want this. The excel file should be downloaded using `onclick` event and not when refreshing.

I am using this code please check

```
require_once("excelwriter.inc.php");

if(isset($_POST['act1']) && $_POST['act1']=="submit")
{
//$t=time();
$excel=new ExcelWriter('ADCL'.time().'.xls');

if($excel==false)
    echo $excel->error;

// this will create heading of each column in excel file
$myArr=array("File No.","Company Name","Entity Status","City","Landline");

$excel->writeLine($myArr);
```

Now fetch data from database table, there is a new line create each time loop runs

Please check and provide me the solution

```
$qry=mysql_query("select * from alig_clients");

if($qry!=false)
{
    $i=1;

    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        $myArr=array($i,$res['clfileno'],$res['clcname'],$res['clemail']);
        $excel->writeLine($myArr);
        $i++;
    }
}
```

java script function

```
<script language="javascript">
function Download()
{
  window.open('ADCL+time()+xls');
}
</script>
```

And the included file code which has been included on the top are as follows:-

```
<?php

    Class ExcelWriter
    {

        var $fp=null;
        var $error;
        var $state="CLOSED";
        var $newRow=false;

        /*
        * @Params : $file  : file name of excel file to be created.
        * @Return : On Success Valid File Pointer to file
        *           On Failure return false  
        */

        function ExcelWriter($file="")
        {
            return $this->open($file);
        }

        /*
        * @Params : $file  : file name of excel file to be created.
        *           if you are using file name with directory i.e. test/myFile.xls
        *           then the directory must be existed on the system and have permissioned properly
        *           to write the file.
        * @Return : On Success Valid File Pointer to file
        *           On Failure return false  
        */
        function open($file)
        {
            if($this->state!="CLOSED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Another file is opend .Close it to save the file";
                return false;
            }   

            if(!empty($file))
            {
                $this->fp=@fopen($file,"w+");
            }
            else
            {
                $this->error="Usage : New ExcelWriter('fileName')";
                return false;
            }   
            if($this->fp==false)
            {
                $this->error="Error: Unable to open/create File.You may not have permmsion to write the file.";
                return false;
            }
            $this->state="OPENED";
            fwrite($this->fp,$this->GetHeader());
            return $this->fp;
        }

        function close()
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            if($this->newRow)
            {
                fwrite($this->fp,"</tr>");
                $this->newRow=false;
            }

            fwrite($this->fp,$this->GetFooter());
            fclose($this->fp);
            $this->state="CLOSED";
            return ;
        }
        //check it

        function GetHeader()
        {
            $header = <<<EOH
                <html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
                xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

                <head>
                <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
                <meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
                 <o:DocumentProperties>
                  <o:LastAuthor>Sriram</o:LastAuthor>
                  <o:LastSaved>2005-01-02T07:46:23Z</o:LastSaved>
                  <o:Version>10.2625</o:Version>
                 </o:DocumentProperties>
                 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                  <o:DownloadComponents/>
                 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                </xml><![endif]-->
                <style>
                <!--table
                    {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
                    mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}
                @page
                    {margin:1.0in .75in 1.0in .75in;
                    mso-header-margin:.5in;
                    mso-footer-margin:.5in;}
                tr
                    {mso-height-source:auto;}
                col
                    {mso-width-source:auto;}
                br
                    {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
                .style0
                    {mso-number-format:General;
                    text-align:general;
                    vertical-align:bottom;
                    white-space:nowrap;
                    mso-rotate:0;
                    mso-background-source:auto;
                    mso-pattern:auto;
                    color:windowtext;
                    font-size:10.0pt;
                    font-weight:400;
                    font-style:normal;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    font-family:Arial;
                    mso-generic-font-family:auto;
                    mso-font-charset:0;
                    border:none;
                    mso-protection:locked visible;
                    mso-style-name:Normal;
                    mso-style-id:0;}
                td
                    {mso-style-parent:style0;
                    padding-top:1px;
                    padding-right:1px;
                    padding-left:1px;
                    mso-ignore:padding;
                    color:windowtext;
                    font-size:10.0pt;
                    font-weight:400;
                    font-style:normal;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    font-family:Arial;
                    mso-generic-font-family:auto;
                    mso-font-charset:0;
                    mso-number-format:General;
                    text-align:general;
                    vertical-align:bottom;
                    border:none;
                    mso-background-source:auto;
                    mso-pattern:auto;
                    mso-protection:locked visible;
                    white-space:nowrap;
                    mso-rotate:0;}
                .xl24
                    {mso-style-parent:style0;
                    white-space:normal;}
                -->
                </style>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
                 <x:ExcelWorkbook>
                  <x:ExcelWorksheets>
                   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
                    <x:Name>srirmam</x:Name>
                    <x:WorksheetOptions>
                     <x:Selected/>
                     <x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents>
                     <x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects>
                     <x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>
                    </x:WorksheetOptions>
                   </x:ExcelWorksheet>
                  </x:ExcelWorksheets>
                  <x:WindowHeight>10005</x:WindowHeight>
                  <x:WindowWidth>10005</x:WindowWidth>
                  <x:WindowTopX>120</x:WindowTopX>
                  <x:WindowTopY>135</x:WindowTopY>
                  <x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure>
                  <x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows>
                 </x:ExcelWorkbook>
                </xml><![endif]-->
                </head>

                <body link=blue vlink=purple>
                <table x:str border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style='border-collapse: collapse;table-layout:fixed;'>
EOH;
            return $header;
        }

        function GetFooter()
        {
            return "</table></body></html>";
        }

        /*
        * @Params : $line_arr: An valid array 
        * @Return : Void
        */

        function writeLine($line_arr)
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            if(!is_array($line_arr))
            {
                $this->error="Error : Argument is not valid. Supply an valid Array.";
                return false;
            }
            fwrite($this->fp,"<tr>");
            foreach($line_arr as $col)
                fwrite($this->fp,"<td class=xl24 width=64 >$col</td>");
            fwrite($this->fp,"</tr>");
        }

        /*
        * @Params : Void
        * @Return : Void
        */
        function writeRow()
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            if($this->newRow==false)
                fwrite($this->fp,"<tr>");
            else
                fwrite($this->fp,"</tr><tr>");
            $this->newRow=true; 
        }

        /*
        * @Params : $value : Coloumn Value
        * @Return : Void
        */
        function writeCol($value)
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            fwrite($this->fp,"<td class=xl24 width=64 >$value</td>");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing the link to Excel.

Comment: hi mark this is the link please check---><span><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Download();"><button class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download Excel</button></a></span>

Comment: Would a j-script tag be more relevant than excel?